# "чистка" строки python

Tags: python

В общем, картина такая: Через сокеты приходит сообщение в таком виде:

```
b'1\n'
```

Нужно его почистить. Грубо говоря, чтобы можно было сделать что-то типа этого:

```
if request == "1":
    message = "Got '1'"
if request == "2":
    message = "2"
```

Comment: bStr = b'1\n'
print bStr[0]

Comment: `rstrip()`, если нужно только справа лишнее (пробельные символы в данном случае) убрать, или `strip()`, если с обеих сторон.

Comment: `rstrip('\n')`, если нужно убрать только переводу строк.

Comment: @CrazyProgrammist, укажите в метках, какую версию Python используете.

Answer (score 0):

```
request = b'1\n' 
request2 = b'2\n' 


if '1' in request:
    print 'Got 1'
if '2' in request2:
    print 'Got 2'
```

Comment: `request = b'12'` ...

Comment: это TypeError на Питоне 3. Не смешивайте байты и Unicode (текст).

Comment: @LinuxGuide, перед выкладыванием ответа желательно пробовать запустить свой код.

Comment: @insolor Ну , запустил, и?

Comment: @LinuxGuide, 1 - проверка нахождения обычной строки внутри байтовой - ошибка типизации. 2 - print без скобок как в Python2, но bytes литералы, как в Python3 - ошибка синтаксиса.

Comment: @insolor 1) А к чему в данном случае приведет ошибка типизации? 2) Почему интерпретатор не воспринимает это как ошибку синтаксиса?

Comment: @LinuxGuide, 2 - воспринимает: https://ideone.com/Y3RAKR 1 - если исправить скобки у print, то будет в вам ошибка типиазации: https://ideone.com/2UTmqe

Comment: @insolor Я пишу на 2 ветке питона, никаких ошибок даже если что-либо исправлять(хотя вопрос зачем, что то исправлять, ну какой в этом смысл?) нету. Какие тут могут быть утверждения/вопросы. https://ideone.com/sbI8MS

Comment: @LinuxGuide, в вопросе неявно предполагается, что используется Python3. "Через сокеты приходит сообщение в таком виде `b'1\n'`" - если бы использовался Python2, то это было бы просто `'1\n'`. Хотя, конечно, стоило бы уточнить у автора вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

```
request = b'1\n'

request = request.rstrip()  # Убирает все пробельные символы в конце (в том числе перенос строки)
# или
request = request.strip()  # Убирает все пробельные символы с обеих сторон

if request == b"1":  # Байтовую строку сравниваем с байтовой строкой, т.к. "1" != b"1"
    message = "Got '1'"
if request == b"2":
    message = "2"
```